# How to make a "Spinner" to improve php form security?

Tags: php, security, spinner

This article about php form security:

http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html

... mentions a "spinner" as:

> The spinner is a hidden field used for
>   a few things: it hashes together a
>   number of values that prevent
>   tampering and replays, and is used to
>   obscure field names. The spinner is an
>   MD5 hash of:
>
> ```
> * The timestamp,
> * The client's IP address,
> * The entry id of the blog entry being commented on, and
> * A secret.
> ```
>
> The field names on the form are all
>   randomized. They are hashes of the
>   real field name, the spinner, and a
>   secret. The spinner gets a fixed field
>   name, but all other fields on the
>   form, including the submission
>   buttons, use hashed field names.

**Does anyone have a code sample of how to implement this on a php page containing a form and the associated php form submission script?**

I don't want to use AJAX, just PHP.

Comment: This is security though obscurity and it will not stop all spiders. For instance this will not fool NTOSpider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the following:

```
  On Page Submit:
  <?php
    $spinnerKey = 'spin';
    $spinner = $_POST[$spinnerKey];
    $values = array();

    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
      if ($key !== $spinnerKey)
      {
        $values[deHash($key, $spinner)] = $value;
      }
    }
?>

A 'deHash' example:
<?php

    # You have to define deHash based on your hash but it 
    # would look something like this:
    var $_rainbowTable = array();
    var $_expectedKeys = array();

    function deHash($hashedkey, $spinner)
    {
        $rt = $this->getRainbowTable($spinner);

        return isset($rt[$hashedKey])
          ? $rt[$hashedKey])
          : NULL;
    }

    function getRainbowTable($spinner)
    { 
        if (count($this->_rainbowTable) > 0)
            return $this->_rainbowTable;

        foreach ($this->_expectedKeys as $key)
        {
            $this->_rainbowTable[hash($key, $spinner)] == $key;
        }

        return $this->_rainbowTable;
    }
  ?>
```

Ultimately though I don't see how this stops bots submitting your page - it just stops people's "email/user/pass" remember browser plugin from working.

Comment: You're missing the point of "hash function" if you refer to reversing one.  I think you mean encryption / decryption.

Comment: I'm using reversible in the same sense you are when you say the key can be worked out from the hash function. deHash would use a rainbow table generated from the hash of your spinner and the expected field names and then use your hashedkey as a lookup in that table to return the actual key, or a null otherwise.

Comment: See my updated example. I corrected the terminology because I got the impression you meant encyrption/decryption since you talked about reversing.

Answer (score 0):

What if at page load create sessions with random values. 
For example 
`$_SESSION['name_for_email'] = 'something_random';`

Then input field

```
<input type="text" 
name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SESSION['name_for_email'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");?>"
>
```

Seems better to use ajax. Visitor clicks Send, pass all data to external php, in the external php call `$_SESSION['name_for_email']`, so can know email field name.

If without ajax, then post and page reloads, but at top of page new `$_SESSION['name_for_email']` created. So php code to process input form must be before define `$_SESSION['name_for_email']`

If many input fields, then must use many sessions. May be better some simplified version.

```
$_SESSION['name_for_email'] = 'something_random';

<input type="text" 
name="field1<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SESSION['name_for_email'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");?>"
>
```

Just need to remember, that `field1` is for email, `field2` for name and so on.

But ... thinking again. The main question is that bot either would not have `$_SESSION['name_for_email']` or for bot the value would be incorrect. Ok, bot "sees" email, "types" email.

If define some hidden field with `$_SESSION['name_for_email']` and before processing input check if `$_SESSION['name_for_email']` is the same as in the hidden input field, i suppose would be the same effect. Because, if bot would know correct random value, then input field names also would be correct.